# Blender: calculation of elevation and rotation angle from plane

Tags: 3d, blender, geometry

I have a generic plane (any location, any rotation around every axis) with its normal axis passing by the center. Then I have a generic point and I need to find the elevation and the rotation angle from the normal of the plane (as described before).

I need a solution that uses bones and constraints (drivers if necessary).

**Note:** to make it easy to understand. I am a little man standing over the plane. I want to know the pitch and the yaw (taking the upper edge center as the North) I need to apply to my head to look to the generic point.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if it is too difficult to understand :)